# Is Not Null works - Is Null does not

Tags: ms-access

I am making a grade entering system in Access, and I am running into some issues with a query.

One of my queries gets the class roster of a class. It takes in the students information, and then it also displays a grade next to their name. For the grade entry system, I only want to have students that do not have a grade already entered to appear.

To do this, in my `Grade` field, I have tried to set the `Criteria` to `Is Null`.

This is not working as it just does not display any student at all. The weird thing is, whenever I set it to `Is Not Null`, it shows me all of the students that have grades entered, and ignores all the students without a grade like I would expect.

So, since the students without grades are left out when the `Criteria` is set to `Is Not Null`, that leads me to believe that a student without a grade is `null`

So, I am very confused why setting the `Criteria` to `Is Null`, just leaves me with no results.

I am very new to Access, so if there is some important information I need to provide for adequate help, please let me know!

Comment: Looks strange. What is `Grade` field data type? If text, try to check against an empty string (`""`), also try to replace `Grade is null` by `Nz([Grade],"")=""`. Do you apply criteria in the query directly to the table to another query? The query may change data type

Comment: This is a text field with letter grades? Then the field is not null. An empty string looks like null but they are not the same. This is why I do not allow empty string in text fields. Somehow field has empty string.

Comment: @SergeyS. if I do the (`""`) for an empty string, then it works. Is this the same as doing `Is Null`, and if so do you know why `Is Null` is not working?

Comment: @June7 It is a text field. But if they are not null, why do the empty strings not appear when the `criteria` is set to `Is Not Null`?

Comment: An empty (zero-length) string is different from Null. You should test for both cases (e.g. `IS NOT NULL OR <> ""` or `IS NULL OR = ""`)

Comment: Sorry, I reread question and I had missed that detail. This is weird. If there is no criteria then all the records (with and without grade) display? Edit question to show sample data and the query SQL statement.

Comment: If you are using the GUI to create your query try using just `NULL` instead of `IS NULL` in the criteria field. Also make sure that this is the only criteria in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your join is a standard join. That means ONLY those with a parent record (student will ONLY show). If the child record that contains the grade does not exist, then they don't appear in your query. Fire up the query builder, and double click on the join line - change it to a left join (the option that says to include all students).

Now, when you run the query, records with a grade row will show, and those without will result in the grade column being null. Now, both of your conditions can and should work. It not the condition that is failing but your query not showing any students without a grade regardless of your condition that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I may be misinterpreting your instructions, but my `Grades` field is not connected to any other tables. The students are connected to the grade entry table and the table that stores the course information, but the Grades are specific to one table.

Comment: Ok, then, we assume your sql looks like (Grade is Null) or (Grade Is Not Null). So you sql will look like either syntax. (so, my assume about this being a join to another table is WRONG on my part. So, try with (Grade is Null), or (Grade is not Null) in your sql.

Comment: It is also possible that you are allowing null strings "ZLS". This means the column looks empty, but is saving a ZLS. You might want to change the table desing, and turn off the ability to store ZLS (zero length strings - I in fact suggest you do).